# What is the difference between enum and object in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, enums

I am trying to access values of a map via enum and also make a translation ready app for all the strings in it.
Both concerns overlap and I have to decide between using enums or just object in JSON format.

So what exactly is the difference and useage between an enum and an object?

For example:

- I can use enums to access arrays as well as inserting labels and other stuff like

```js
const enum FieldNames {
  FirstField: "Field One",
  SecondField: "Field Two"
};
    
someFieldArray[FieldNames.FirstField].label = FieldNames.FirstField;
someFieldArray[FieldNames.SecondField].label = FieldNames.SecondField;
```

- Or I can achieve the same behaviour via object

```js
const FieldNames = {
  FirstField: "Field One",
  SecondField: "Field Two"
};

someFieldArray[FieldNames.FirstField].label = FieldNames.FirstField;
someFieldArray[FieldNames.SecondField].label = FieldNames.SecondField;
```

I really do not get the benefit choosing enums over simple objects. In my opinion an object has much more benefits without any downsides.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

## Enum

An enum may give you additional benefits, if you want the features:

```
const enum FieldNamesEnum {
  FirstField = "Field One",
  SecondField = "Field Two"
};

let x: FieldNamesEnum;

x = FieldNamesEnum.FirstField;
x = FieldNamesEnum.SecondField;

// Error - not assignable to FieldNames
x = 'str';

// Cannot assign
FieldNamesEnum.FirstField = 'str';
```

Importantly, you can't assign to the enum members and types are checked to the enum members, rather than string.

Additionally, because you have used a `const enum` in your example, the enum won't exist at runtime and all the references will be substituted for the literal values (if you used a plain `enum` the enum *would* exist at runtime).

## Object

Compare this to the object example:

```
const FieldNames = {
  FirstField: "Field One",
  SecondField: "Field Two"
};

let y: string;

y = FieldNames.FirstField;
y = FieldNames.SecondField;

// Oops it works
y = 'str';

// Oops it works

FieldNames.FirstField = 'str';
```

## Union

If you don't need the full enum, but want to limit the values, you can use a union of literal values:

```
type FieldNames = "Field One" | "Field Two";

let x: FieldNames;

x = "Field One";
x = "Field Two";

// Error - not allowed
x = "Field Three";
```

Comment: But is it possible to make encapsulated enums?

Comment: fabulous explanation!! Specially the one related to non-assigning of enum members.

Comment: The problem with your solution is, that you set the type of `y` to `string` and not to the actual type of the values of the `FieldNames` object which should be the one from @Martynas Skučas below. Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59932722/1681085

Comment: enum's behavior can be achieved using objects

Answer (score 34):

I don't aggre with @Fenton. Objects are the type safe.

```js
const FieldNames = {
  FirstField: 'Field One',
  SecondField: 'Field Two',
} as const;

type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];
let y: ValueOf<typeof FieldNames>;

y = FieldNames.FirstField;
y = FieldNames.SecondField;

// TS2322: Type '"str"' is not assignable to type '"Field One" | "Field Two"'.
y = 'str';

// TS2540: Cannot assign to 'FirstField' because it is a read-only property
FieldNames.FirstField = 'str';
```

Comment: I like your thinking. Setting `y` to type string is not the best way. Very good answer in my opinion. However, it does not answer the whole question.

Comment: `as const` was introduced in TS 3.4 which was released in 2019. And the original answer from @Fenton was posted in 2017. I think this is a valid updated answer.

Also in fact, the TS official docs now says that most of the time `as const` can work to replace enum.

Comment: @coolgod can you point me where in the docs is the "as const will replace enum most of the time" is said? I could find it.

Comment: @EduRuiz https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#objects-vs-enums

Answer (score 11):

```
function (foo: FieldNames) { }
```

If `FieldNames` is an object, this means this function expects an instance which has the properties `FirstField` and `SecondField`. If `FieldNames` is an enum (in which case it should be singular, not plural), this means the function expects *one of the values of `FieldNames`*, namely `"Field One"` or `"Field Two"`.

Very different usage.

Comment: But you can achieve that behaviour by just using interfaces and/or classes.

Comment: How do you easily define an interface or class that says "one of these values"?

Comment: An abstract class with static FieldName properties? Or something like that.

Comment: The above type hint says `foo` can be either the value `"Field One"` or `"Field Two"`. It could be written as `foo: "Field One" | "Field Two"`. How do you express that as a class with static properties?

Comment: An enum as a type hint says "the variable may take one of the values in this list". An enum as an object makes those values easily accessible by something like constants (e.g. `FieldName.FirstField`); you can change the underlying value without needing to rewrite all the code that uses it. – That is all very different from classes/objects, in which you can instantiate an object from a class and pass that object around and type hint against the object type.

Comment: You can do `function (foo: keyof FieldNames) { }` instead

Answer (score 5):

In the Typescript language handbook, you have a dedicated section talking about that: [Objects vs Enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#objects-vs-enums).

Personally, when I need a type with a set of options, I prefer using Typescript enum, because it is easier to use. With the enum definition, you have the type and also the way to access the options. To implement the same aproach with an object, you need to define the object `as const` and also define an extra type based on it.

Answer (score 1):

this should be main reason.. you can use enum as a type so one of following options, but you cant define cosnt object as a type, it will have all options in one obj :)

you can also do this

```
type FieldNames = "Field One" | "Field Two";
```

but if list is long, enum is much better,
in ES6 enum is pure useless just use obejct
but in typescript its a type and its a main benefit in my opition