# Typescript: Cannot find namespace

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have the following simple NodeJS code:

```
const express = require('express');

const server: express.Application = express();
```

I'm adding Typescript to my project and am new to it so forgive me. With the above code I get the following issues/errors:

For the require:

```
var require: NodeRequire (id: string) => any (+1 overload)
'require' call may be converted to an import.
```

For the express.Application usage:

```
Cannot find namespace 'express'.
```

If I switch the 'require' to 'import' it fixes the namespace error but is no longer valid Node code so doesn't run (throws a new error about unexpected token for the import).

What's the correct way to write Node code like this with Typescript to avoid these errors?

My tsconfig.json looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "lib": ["dom", "es2017"],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "esnext",
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
}
```

Comment: How is your project set up; what's in `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: Try `declare function require(name:string);` at the top. Typescript doesnt support require by default

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've updated my question with the tsconfig

Comment: @Deckerz Would I have to do that in every Node file I use require in then? That seems annoying if so.

Comment: npm i @types/express... for typescript definition. it should fix "Cannot find namespace 'express'."

Comment: @JurajKocan Unfortunately that didn't work to remove that error

Comment: hm thats wierd... can you share repo?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After a lot of wasted time, it turns out this was due to the `module` setting in the tsconfig file which should be:

```
"module": "commonjs"
```

This means Typescript will output common js modules instead of ES6 modules, meaning the code will run correctly as NodeJS code. I was therefore able to change require to import, since it compiles.

Answer (score 82):

In case you are a React dev that ends up here as I did - if there is JSX syntax in the file, try changing the extension of the file from `.ts` to `.tsx`.

Comment: I was ready to pull out my hair

Answer (score 1):

### Use enum instead of object

My code satisfies all the answers mentioned above. `"module": "commonjs"` and my file is already a `.tsx` file.

Still getting this error. Here is how I got this error.

In my payload, I have a key(shape) based on which some other details of the payload are dependent.

```
export const SHAPES = {
  SQUARE: "square",
  CIRCLE: "circle",
};
```

> Note: I am using this SHAPES object to store constants

If you are trying to use the value of an object as a type for an interface then you will get this error.

```
interface ICirclePayload {
  shape: SHAPES.CIRCLE;
  details: {
    radius: number;
  };
}

interface ISquarePayload {
  shape: SHAPES.SQUARE;
  details: {
    length: number;
  };
}
```

You will get the below error for SHAPES in both the interfaces

```
Cannot find namespace 'SHAPES'.ts(2503)
```

### SOLUTION FROM HERE

Change `object` to `enum`

```
export const enum SHAPES {
  SQUARE = "square",
  CIRCLE = "circle",
}
```

With the above code, the error should be resolved.

Consider reading [What is the difference between enum and object in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47351323/what-is-the-difference-between-enum-and-object-in-typescript)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to use *import* instead of *require*:

```
import * as express from 'express';
```

Comment: OP already wrote in his question, that this would fix the error, but no longer is valid Node code, therefore another error gets thrown.

Comment: This causes a Typescript error on express() of `Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'typeof e' has no compatible call signatures` and also when I try to run the code, since import isn't valid NodeJS code it wouldn't work anyway.

Answer (score 0):

## tsConfig compilerOptions "types"

For me it was the `compilerOptions` -> `types` that contained a type, in this case *"googlemaps"* instead of *"google.maps"* for namespace declaration.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": [
       ...
      "google.maps"
       ...
    ],
  }
}
```

From the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#types):

> If types is specified, only packages listed will be included in the global scope